# How do I reduce a spark dataframe from kafka and collect the result?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, reduce

I have a dataframe created from a kafka stream. I want to reduce it to a single value and then use that single value in my program.

````
```scala
import sparkSession.implicits._
val df = sparkSession
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", ...)
  .option("subscribe", "theTopic")
  .load()

val result = df
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as json")
  .map(json => getAnInt(json))
  .reduce { (x, y) =>
    if (x > y) x else y
  }



 someOtherFunction(result)
 ```
````

I am expecting to have the stream reduced to a single value that I can then use in the rest of my program. Instead it fails with:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();;
>   kafka
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnsupportedOperationChecker$.throwError(UnsupportedOperationChecker.scala:389)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.U...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `writeStream` over a streaming dataframe. I am not sure if you intend to have this streaming dataframe. If you remove `readStream` and use `read` instead, you might solve this problem!

Comment: That was it. Thanks!